# Daterangepicker, pass data range to page.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Just learning jquery\ajax will be very grateful for help!

I need to pass the date range that user choose (http://www.daterangepicker.com/)
to a PAGE.PHP page for filtering, and return the data from PAGE.PHP.
How can I send the date-range values to PAGE.PHP, without submit button, after user choose the data range?

Many thanks!
My code is:

```
<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
      // alert("A new date range was chosen:");
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can do something like this:

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
         $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "PAGE.PHP",
           data: {startDate: picker.startDate, endDate: picker.endDate}
        }).done(function(response){
            // Do something with response here
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (error) {
            // And handle errors here
            console.log(error);
        });
      });
```

Don't forget about server-side validation and CSRF-protection.

Comment: With this, you need to click `apply` in order to send data ! But the OP stated **without submit button** :D

Comment: Apply is not equal submit =) This event fired after user selected some date  or pressed apply button

Comment: Sure! but I think that's what to OP meant :D

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood him then. I thought he was talking about html "submit" button.

Comment: Hey. Thanks! Apply is must to be pressed, because only in this way the daterangepicker will display the range that user choose, inside the field. Sorry for misunderstanding! You have just small error, you mast to pass to the Daterangepicker the format of the data. So it must be `startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')` for example. Also, the data in such way passed in unix timestamp, so I did `date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $startDate);`for example. Besides this, works great. Thank you! @Ismail RBOUH thank you too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use input change event and send an ajax request to your server like this:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#datefilter").change(function(e) {
    if(!this.value) return;
    var dates = this.value.split(" - ");
    $.post('page.php', {startDate: dates[0], endDate: dates[1]}, function(data) {
        //Show you data in the page
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$startDate = strtotime($_POST['startDate']);
$endDate = strtotime($_POST['endDate']);
//You can format the date using date($format, $startDate|$endDate);
//Make a query then echo the result that will be recieved by the ajax function
```

Please note that you must verify your `$startDate/$endDate`.

I hope this will help you.